# Are the roots of $x^{h+k}-m(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}+\cdots +x+1)$, either real or complex, distinct, where $m,h,k$ are positive integers with $m,h>1$?

Tags: polynomials, roots, fibonacci-numbers

The recursive relationship $F_n=F_{n-1}+mF_{n-h-1}-mF_{n-h-k-1}$ or equivalently $F_n=m(F_{n-h-1}+\cdots +F_{n-h-k})$ comes from looking at Fibonacci's rabbit problem but assuming each litter has $m\geq 2$ pairs, they start giving birth each month after $h\geq 2$ months, and they give birth for just $k$ months. To show that there is a nice explicit formula for the populations each month it would be nice to know that the corresponding characteristic polynomial, $f(x)=x^{h+k}-m(x^{k-1}+x^{k-2}+\cdots +x+1)$ or equivalently $g(x)=f(x)(x-1)=x^{h+k+1}-x^{h+k}-mx^k+m$ has distinct real or complex roots. I have been able to show that there are no repeated roots with modulus at most 1 (using $f(x)$ and $f^\prime (x)$) and that the largest root is real and less than $m+1$. If this polynomial always has distinct roots, then there is an explicit (Binet-type) formula for $F_n$, just like there is in the case of Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: For $k=1$ the $f(x)=x^{h+1}-m$ has no repeated roots as $(f,f')=1$. If $f$ has repeated roots then it must be reducible (as $\gcd(f,f')\neq 1$), but for $k \geq 2$ a computer search suggests $f(x)$ is irreducible most of the time (also notice for example whenever there is a prime $p\mid m$ such that $p^2\nmid m$, then it is irreducible by Eisenstein. Though some examples where $f(x)$ is not irreducible and this argument does not work are $(m,h,k)=(8,4,2),(8,4,5),(8,5,7),(32,3,2),(32,7,3)$.

Comment: I should clarify that complex roots are also of interest, though ruling our real repeated roots is helpful.

Comment: What Sil said. Further, I think your polynomial is missing the term corresponding  to either $F_n$ or $F_{n-1}$. Anyway, unless $x=1$ happens to be a zero of that  polynomial it may be easier (I haven't checked) to work with $P(x)(x-1)$ instead of $P(x)$ because telescoping leads to $P(x)(x-1)$ having less terms.

Comment: Also note that even with repeated roots the linear recurrence will have an explicit formula.